# 2nd degree differential equation with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a really hard time solving

> $$xy'' + 2y' + 4xy = 0$$

I basically tried a lot of substitutions and series but couldn't find it.
I realize this isn't as hard as I make it out to be so I'm assuming there is a certain trick that I am not seeing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let be $z = xy$. We have $z''= 2y' + xy''$ e the equation becomes
$$
z'' + 4 z = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the Taylor series. It will give you the right solution. Alternatively, you can try to reduce the 2nd order ODE to a system of 1st order ODEs. But anyway, the Taylor series seems to be an always viable approach.